# Executing a certain command for files in multiple subfolders at once in windows powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with multiple subfolders containing PDF files which I am renaming by executing this command in each of the subfolder;

```
get-childitem *.pdf | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("certainword", "") }
```

So is there any way to rename all PDF files in each of the subfolder at once in one command?

Comment: Note that `get-childitem` has a *recursive* switch: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2 and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-explore-nested-directories-and-files/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks a lot for helping me out. I didn't knew about that as I am just learning.

Comment: That's a good way to learn: take an existing statement, and make a change to suit it to your needs. Best wishes learning PowerShell!

Comment: @LilyWilliam So the command to then pipe over to the `foreach` is `Get-ChildItem *.pdf -Recurse` to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments, you should use `-Recurse` parameter to apply the cmdlet to subfolders.

A small change to you cmdlet is that you don't need `ForEach`. You can pipe the files' list directly to `Rename-Item`, then use `-NewName` parameter.

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'certainword', '' }
```